# How to install npm package globally only if not already installed?

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, bower, npm-install

I'm writing a build script and it executes commands like:

- `npm install bower -g`
- `npm install gulp -g`

Installing these packages will take around 30-60 seconds on my machine even if they are already installed (e.g. installed from previous run of the build script).

I was thinking there could be a way to detect if *bower* or *gulp* are already installed and in that case skip the installation to save some time during the build.

Is something like that possible? How would I do that?

I'm using Windows and PowerShell, but I suppose some solutions in bash might be possible to port to Windows...

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but it should not take 30-60 seconds if they are already on your machine, unless it's trying to determine a version match.  If you're explicit on the version in your package.json and bower.json, it won't need to take time to hit the registry to see if there is a newer version available.

Comment: @Paul: Thanks for the response. I thought that package.json was not being used in global installs. I actually don't think I have bower listed in my package.json file at all. Also bower.json is not related to this since all of this is npm installs...

Comment: Ok, I was completely misreading, thanks.  So, you're right about the .json files not being used for global installs, sorry.  That said, my comment stands about using a specific version in the command that you're running the install with.

Comment: @Paul: Yeah, good idea. I tried running `npm install gulp@3.9.1 -g` couple of times and it still takes around 10 seconds each time I run it, but I think it is a bit faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Win7+ you can use `where <command>` e.g.

```
@echo off
where gulp > nul
if %ERRORLEVEL% GEQ 1 (npm i gulp -g) else (echo Gulp already installed)
```

Comment: Thanks, works quite well. There's also an alternative with `Get-Command` when using PowerShell.